# How can we step over a function call in GDB?

Tags: c++, gdb

I want to understand how we can step over a function call. For instance, consider the following program:

```
 #include <iostream>
 #include "test.h"

 using std::cout;
 using std::endl;

 Uint u;

 int main()
 {
     cout << "execution starting..." << endl;
     cout << u.a << endl;
     cout << "execution completed" << endl;
 }
```

In GDB, I set a breakpoint at the 11th line (`cout << "execution starting..." << endl;`) with `break 11`.

Now I want to step over all instructions which are going to be invoked in printing `"execution starting..."` and stop at the `<<` operator call that prints the `endl` symbol.

How can I do that? Which command should I use?

Comment: `next [count]` *This is similar to step, but function calls that appear within the line of code are executed without stopping* https://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb/Continuing-and-Stepping.html#Continuing-and-Stepping

Answer (score 15, accepted):

In GDB, [`step`](https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Continuing-and-Stepping.html#index-s-_0028step_0029) means stepping into (will go inside functions called), and [`next`](https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Continuing-and-Stepping.html#index-n-_0028next_0029) means stepping over (continue and stop at the next line).

But in your particular case, `next` may not be what you want, and I would suggest to first `step` into the function printing "execution starting...", then use [`finish`](https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Continuing-and-Stepping.html#index-fin-_0028finish_0029) to continue until it returns, so that the program will stop at `<< endl`.

Answer (score 1):

If you set a breakpoint, then just use `continue` to resume execution until that breakpoint. Unless you want to *skip* those calls altogether, then you would just set `$eip` or `$rip` to your breakpoint'ed address like
`set $[e|r]ip=0x[your_address]`